# Prime Divisor of the Sum of Two Squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, gaussian-integers

I'm struggling something immensely to make sense of the following:

https://meiji163.github.io/post/sum-of-squares/#sums-of-two-squares

> Factoring an integer in Gaussian integers is closely related to representing that integer as the sum of two squares.
> If we can factor $p = (a+bi)(a-bi)$ then $p=a^2 + b^2$.
> Moreover, if $q = (c+di)(c-di)$ is also the sum of two squares, then so is $pq$ since
> $$pq = ((ac-bd)+i(ad+bc))((ac-bd)-i(ac+bd)) .$$
> From this we can determine all integers that can be represented as a sum of two squares by looking at the primes in its prime factorization (in regular integers).
> For example, $15=3 \cdot 5$ is not the sum of squares because we can’t factor the $3$ in Gaussian integers.

This should be easy, but for some reason my mind is still stuck *somewhere* on some trivial point. I just don't understand how you get from "if $x$ and $y$ both have property A, then so does their product $xy$" to "if $z$ has property $A$ and $x$ is a prime factor of $z$, then $x$ also has property $A$".

Someone please save me from this fog of ignorance!

Comment: The thing  that addresses separate factors:  if $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q $ for (positive) prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$  then both $x,y \equiv 0 \pmod q,$ so that $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {q^2} $  Induction says that the exponent for $q$  must be even.

Comment: It's not true that if $z$ is the sum of two squares and $x$ is a prime factor of $z$, then $x$ is the sum of two squares.  For example, $9 = 0 + 3^2$ is the sum of two squares, but $3$ is not the sum of two squares.

Comment: This blog does seem to have skipped some of the usual justification given! It's not a totally trivial fact indeed, and in this case it may be that $z$ can be written as a sum of squares but a prime factor cannot (eg $z = 45$, $p = 3$). The argument is a bit more subtle than that - you can find it eg as Theorem 6 [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/4400twosquares.pdf) or in section 2.6 [here](https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/IB_L/groups_rings_and_modules.pdf).

Comment: There is a middle ground when the (form) class number  is bigger than one. For discriminant $-20$   we get something similar for $x^2 + 5 y^2.$  This obviously represents $6$  with integers $x=1, y=1.$  Of course, $x^2 + 5 y^2$  does not represent $2$ or $3.$  However, the other form $2 x^2 + 2 x y + 3 y^2$  obviously does represent both $2,3$ In general, if $m,n$   are both represented by  $2 x^2 + 2 x y + 3 y^2,$  there is also a representation of the product, $x^2 + 5 y^2 = mn.$  Along with $2,$ $2 x^2 + 2 x y + 3 y^2$  represents all primes $p \equiv 3,7 \pmod{20}$